# Install HDP 2.2 on CentOS 7

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, centos7, ambari

As I can see HDP 2.2 needs Centos 6.5 as an operation system, probably because Ambari needs Centos 6.5. My question is if anyone has installed it on Centos 7. Is there any hard dependencies that will not allow me to complete the installation successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambari 2.2+ can be installed successfully and works fine on CentOS 7. Then you can install HDP 2.0+.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there are no hard dependencies, per se. However Ambari itself looks at the operating system version, and if its CentOS 7, it'll stop the install.

In order to work around that you'd need to edit Ambari's source code.

Comment: not really a source code (in most cases). Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/44392902/1421254 , it describes how to  customize dependencies.

Comment: I seem to recall hunting this down in the source back when the question was asked, but my memory is pretty hazy! Nice to know that Ambari has a better general solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just consult the official Installation Guide for a relevant Ambari version
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Install+Ambari+2.2.0+from+Public+Repositories

It's an up-to-date source of OS compatibility information.
Here you can see that Centos 7 is officially supported.